# Determine the branch cuts of f(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function f(z) = $({z^2} + 1)^{1/2}$, that is, the principal value of the function f(z) = $({z^2} + 1)^{1/2}$.

Determine the branch cuts of f(z); check the discontinuity of the branch along the branch cuts.

How do I determine those branch cuts?

Answer (score 1):

They are where $(z^2+1)$ is negative real, so the square-root has a discontinuity.